# How to add commas between numbers I found in a website

Tags: python, list

Suppose i have this website https://adventofcode.com/2020/day/1/input and in it a lot of numbers are given. i want all these numbers in a list but when i copy paste them there are no commas between them and it is all just one large number. is there a way i can put commas between the numbers easily rather than manually?

like
the numbers are: 1446
1893
1827
1565
1728
497
1406
1960
1986
1945

I copy paste them in a python list like,

```py
l = [1446 1893 1827 1565 1728 497 1406 1960 1986 1945]
```

Here there are no commas separating the numbers like 1446 and 1839

Can i add commas between them?

Comment: There are many ways. Are you on Windows or a Unix-like system? What editor are you using?

Comment: im on windows and am using pycharm

Comment: It seems that you need a tutorial on string handling, rather than Stack Overflow.  It's not clear, because the "list" you posted is not legal Python.

Comment: Use quotes instead, then `num_list = list( num_string .split() )`

Answer (score 1):

```
string = '1446 1893 1827 1565 1728 497 1406 1960 1986 1945'
l = map(int,string.split(' '))
print(list(l))
```

Output will be

```
[1446, 1893, 1827, 1565, 1728, 497, 1406, 1960, 1986, 1945]
```

I hope this is what you wanted.

Edit:- Renamed the variable name from 'str' to 'string'

Comment: This is mot exactly what he saked for, he was looking for ide tool not a program to convert... anyway i voted up cuz i like it...:)

Comment: And suggest not to use the keyword `str` as it is a saved keyword.. very critic one

Comment: BTW for an IDE or even basic text editor solution, you can pretty much just use find-and-replace in *any* text editor -- search for ` ` (empty space) and replace with `, ` (comma followed by a space) and make the find-and-replace *global* to account for all occurrences.

Comment: @drcossbones if  answer is helpful please accept it vs